# Built-in Keyframes

Tags: keyframes

What is the difference between the built-in keyframes? For some reason, automatic key framing is not working for so I have to manually set it. If anyone has an idea on it, please help.

### Built-in Keyframes

- Available
- BBone Shape
- Delta Location
- Delta Rotation
- Delta Scale
- Location
- LocRot
- LocRotScale
- LocScale
- Rotation
- RotScale
- Scaling
- Visual Location
- Visual LocRot
- Visual LocRotScale
- Visual LocScale
- Visual Rotation
- Visual RotScale
- Visual Scaling
- Whole Character
- Whole Character (Selected bones only)

Note: I am video editing on Blender not modeling.

Comment: Those settings only apply to the 3d view and don't affect the video editing process. Like you said, auto keyframing has no effect either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of these options selects which property will be saved to the keyframe. For example, if I select LocRot it will save a keyframe for location and rotation, However, if I also scale the object, but do not set a scale keyframe, the scale will not be animated.

However, you say you are video editing. These options do not apply to video editing. Try switching to the video editing workflow. If you would like to set a keyframe for a property, hover your mouse over it and press "i". Then move the timeline cursor, change the value, hover again, and press "i". This will animate the desired property.